# Преобразование классов в библиотеку

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, библиотеки, модель

Есть модель ЭВМ с пользовательским интерфейсом. К модели можно подключать программные "внешние устройства". Сейчас они представлены как классы модели с контроллером и формой и "подключаются" через класс Контроллер внешних устройств посредствам интерфейса (фабрика создаёт объект внешнего устройства).
Мне требуется отделить классы внешних устройств с формами в отдельные библиотеки или что-то подобное, что бы пользователь мог просто убирая файл или добавляя файл из папки с приложением, отключать или подключать внешние устройства.
Как это правильно сделать? Скомпилировать каждое "внешнее устройство" отдельно как библиотеку, можно ли так сделать если есть форма? Или есть ещё какие-то варианты?

Comment: ищите решения по динамической подгрузке сборок. Это можно и вручню делать, иои можно пользоваться гтовыми инструментами

Comment: Вариантов куча. Здесь на что фантазии хватит. Ну плюс `FileSystemWatcher` может вам помочь.